# Equivalent in Dojo of element this in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dojo

Is there something like `$(this)` in jQuery but in Dojo?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
dojo.ready(function(){
    dojo.query('a').onclick(function(){
        var inter_page = window.location.href;
        var inter_text = thiselementclicked.text();
        if ( inter_text === ""){
            inter_text = thiselementclicked.attr('class');
        }
        var inter_foward = thiselementclicked.href;
        ga('send', 'event', ''+inter_page+'', ''+inter_text+'', ''+inter_foward+'');
    });
});
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Explain about the error or the problem you are facing. So that it will be more appropriate to understand

Comment: g00glen00b has provided the answer, but there's really no need to use jQuery or Dojo to get an attribute when you can use `this.getAttribute('class')`

Answer (score 0):

Works well enough:

```
dojo.query("a").onclick(function (e) {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Or alternatively, if you don't want to act on a list:

```
var el = dojo.byId("myId"); // grab by id, or do another query
dojo.connect(node, "onclick", function () {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: connect is deprecated, should use dojo/on instead

Comment: @RayWadkins: true, but it's still present in the latest version's documentation, and as so many dojo projects are slow to update (as dojo is usually used for rather large web-apps, or at least that was my case back when I used it), I thought it'd be worth mentioning as I don't know what the OP uses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, it's the same in Dojo, just use `query(this)` and you should get a `NodeList` from the current item, for example (in AMD):

```
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-manipulate", "dojo/domReady!"], function(query) {

    query("a").on("click", function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log(query(this).text());
        query(this).attr('class').forEach(function(className) {
             console.log(className);   
        });
    });
});
```

Be aware though, the `.attr('class')` returns a list itself, so to get the actual classnames you have to loop over it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g5m68776/